# Advanced Chart in Excel - column width based on cell value

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am an intermediate excel user struggling to create a specific chart for an internship project. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and have searched the web extensively.

Below is an example chart with example data:

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you describe is a Marimekko chart, or variable width column chart. They can be created in Excel using the Area chart and a well-organised data layout.

Excel MVP and charting guru Jon Peltier has a step by step tutorial here:

http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/marimekko-charts/

Edit: The screenshot shows your data, the data layout required (truncated) and the final chart.

[image]

Create a data table as in columns F to H in the screenshot, insert an Area chart for that data, with column F as the X axis. Change the X axis from category to time axis.  Use the label helper table to add a data series, send it to the secondary axis, make it a line chart, use a date axis. Use the free XY Chart Labeler add-in to place the labels below the data markers of the line. Hide the line, data markers and unwanted axes lines and labels.

Done.

[Download file.](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=FE479525195477F7!2304&authkey=!AD3NU7cwKMFO6FY&ithint=file,.xlsx)

Comment: Cascade charts are similar in construction to Marimekko charts. See [Variable Width Column Charts (Cascade Charts)](http://peltiertech.com/variable-width-column-charts/).